# UPDATE mysql database and the id and the image in relation to the id?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this php file which will update a table in mysql database.

it works to a certain. it will update the name of the product (product_name) and it will update the (date_added) too. but it is not updating the id and as a result the image that was uploaded with that id is not showing!!

here is the code:

```
<?php 
// Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
if (isset($_POST['product_name'])) {

    $product_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_name']);
    // See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM tomProduct WHERE product_name='$product_name' LIMIT 1");
    $productMatch = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ($productMatch > 0) {
        echo 'Sorry you tried to place a duplicate "Product Name" into the system, <a href="index.php">click here</a>';
        exit();
    }
    // Add this product into the database now
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE tomProduct SET product_name='$product_name', date_added=now()") or die (mysql_error());
     $pid = mysql_insert_id();
    // Place image in the folder 
    $newname = "$pid.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../tom/$newname");
    header("location: verify_members.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
```

and here is the form:

```
<form action="verify_members.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="myform" method="post">
<table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
  <tr>
    <td width="20%" align="right">Product Name</td>
    <td width="80%"><label>
      <input name="product_name" type="text" id="product_name" size="64" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Product Image</td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField" />
    </label></td>
  </tr> 
        <tr>      
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add This Item Now" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

anyone knows why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using an `UPDATE` to `INSERT` a record into the database?  That update query would set ALL product_name and date_added fields to `$product_name` and `now()` respectively.

Comment: I don't see an actual INSERT anywhere.

Comment: **Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code** ([why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)), they are 

[deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Use [PDO or MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead

Comment: You are calling `mysql_insert_id()` yet haven't actually `INSERT`ed anything?

Comment: @kingkero, i know mate, i am just working on someone else's script. I have already told them to let me change the script to mysqli but they don't want to. so its their choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_insert_id()` returns the last `INSERT` record, not `UPDATE`.

Comment: so what do I have to use instead?